# Update only permissions etc. with rsync

Tags: permissions, rsync, timestamps, archive, ownership

I'd like to know if the following scenario will update permissions, ownership, timestamps etc.

Say I transfer a folder from a destination to another using `rsync -zr source/ dest/`, and then use the command `rsync -auzr source/ dest/` - will the latter command then update the permissions, ownership, and timestamps or will I have re-transfer all the files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to not copy everything over you will have to do an initial run of `-a --size-only` which will avoid using timestamps to determine how to get things in sync.   after running with `--size-only`, and `-a` rsync will  correct the permissions and timestamps on the destination.  After that you can use just `-a` which is a better check, since files don't always change in size when modified.   Giving you are using `-u` I don't know if that means there are files being written to the destination that should not be overwritten.  I would caution you use `--dry-run` so you are comfortable with the rsync  execution before making any changes.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks.